# Setting HTML custom attributes vs storing information in ID attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Usually when I need some Id of a random object (stored on the server) in JavaScript I'm using the following approach:

```
<div id="chat-wrap-29" class="chat-wrap">...</div>
<div id="chat-wrap-28" class="chat-wrap">...</div>
```

This is how I know that I can retrieve the chat wrap ID in a JS script and send it via AJAX on the server.
In order to get the id I have to retrieve the id attribute (`this.getAttribute("id")`), and do some string manipulation in the script.

An cleaner way would be to use something like this:

```
<div class="chat-wrap" chatId = "29">...</div>
<div class="chat-wrap" chatId = "29">...</div>
```

This way there would be less IDs declared in the DOM and I would avoid that string manipulation. Has this solution any drawbacks? What would be the best practice in the situation I've described?

Thank you!

Comment: It's HTLM5 but you could use the data attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to store data in attributes, you should use [HTML5 `data-*` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) - that's their purpose, as described in [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Some JavaScript libraries, such as [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/data/) have native support for them.